# How to troubleshoot TFS error TF237086 "The work item cannot be saved..."

Tags: msbuild, tfs-workitem

I am getting the following error in a TFS 2010 build:

> The work item '59' could not be updated: 'TF237086: The work item cannot be saved because at least one field contains a value that is not allowed.'

Work item 59 is a basic task I created to associate with my changeset on check-in. I have done no customization to the "task" work item. I get no errors when opening the task up and changing values manually. There is nothing in the build log that gives any clues as to what field is causing the problem.

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something I would do in this case:

1. Check the build service account, there's a high chance that when the work item is associated, its ChangedBy field is updated with this account and the value is not valid. Somebody in MSDN forum suggested checking the list of valid TFS users for a work item (you can open a bug and try typing the name in the AssignedTo field) and see if this account is in that list.
2. Try a checkin by yourself with the same associated task and see what fields are updated (you should be able to see this in the History tab), from there you can figure out the possible fields, and hopefully can guess the one that is in trouble.

If none of this works, I can get some more details and try to repro it on my machine. We'll need to improve error message to specify which fields that are invalid.

Hope this helps.

---

**[Update]**
The cause was indeed that the build service account (NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM) did not have permissions to modify work items. All my attempts to fix this by editing group memberships failed, but I did get the build working without errors by using an unused project contributor's account as the build service account. Changing build service account may require the old build [workspaces to be renamed or reassigned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: I'm using the TFS 2010 HyperV provided on Brian Keller's blog, and have created a new project. I've tried to replicate the permissions that TailSpin toys has, so the "Project Collection Build Service Account" group is a member of the "Contributors" group on the new project. In the valid AssignedTo fields, I can see LOCAL SERVICE, NETWORK SERVICE and TFSREPORTS, but no SYSTEM which I think is the build service account. On TailSpin, LOCAL SERVICE and SYSTEM are in the list but not the other two. Do you know how I go about fixing this?

Comment: Mark - Can you change the build service account to LOCAL SERVICE or NETWORK SERVICE? I'm not very familiar with this stuff, I can dig further but not at the moment.

Comment: It's interesting that I also use TFS2010 and got this error instead: TF42097: A work item could not be created due to a field error. The following fields have incorrect values: Field: 'Changed By' Value: 'SYSTEM', Field: 'Activated By' Value: 'SYSTEM'. So you'll probably need to switch the build service account there. I'll dig in further soon.

Comment: thanks, I'll hopefully get a chance to change build service account soon, and will report back with my findings

Comment: just tried with "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" - all the builds failed due to permissions writing to C:\Build

Comment: TFS permissions or local folder permissions? If it's local folder, please try granting permissions for the new account there. If it's TFS, it means the new account is not updated for the current workspaces (created by the build agents). Easiest solution is to remove the folder and retry the build if you don't have tons of files to sync again. Normally this is done by the TFS Admin Console when you change the build service account, for some reason it doesn't work for you (you might get some detailed errors in the event log).

Comment: I think it's local folder permissions. Will give it a go if I get a chance tomorrow. I suspect I'll end up having to do the same for the drops folder and anywhere else the build service needs to touch though

Comment: ran into yet another roadblock. The build folder can't be used since it has a workspace in use by the SYSTEM user. I don't really want to just go deleting everything in there, so I'll need to work out how to delete this workspace first. (by the way, thanks for your ongoing help on this, really appreciate your patience)

Comment: well, I bit the bullet and deleted the workspaces using `tf workspace /delete "4_1_WIN-GS9MUJITS8;NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"`. This allowed the build to work and the user I selected as the build service (I just selected a regular contributor to the project) now builds and associates work items correctly.

Comment: I forgot, but you probably can also do tf workspace /newowner to change the onwer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: thanks @Duat Le you've been a great help. I've taken the liberty of updating your answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, after restarting VS 2015 IDE and entering credentials to my account on the TFS I was able to get rid of the errror.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Answer (score 0):

After changing the build service account, I got a new error

> The working folder xxxx is already in use by the workspace
>   1_1_SSSSSSSS;NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM on computer SSSSSSSSS.

The solution to that issue is to use the TF utility to delete the workspace(s) associated with the `SYSTEM` build account. I had to copy the TF utility from my Laptop over to our server to run it.

See [TFS Build Service Account change causes Build Failures - “Working Folder in use” Failures](http://blogs.technet.com/b/chrad/archive/2010/04/07/tfs-build-service-account-change-causes-build-failures-working-folder-in-use-failures.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Got the error on a long running build system where the user accounts had not changed.
found the WORKSPACE ID in the build log ran

```
tf.exe workspaces /owner:*
```

to confirm the workspace was on the build server and then ran

```
tf.exe workspace /delete 9_1_BUILDSERVER;OURDOMAIN\TFSBuild
```

to delete it, queued another build and no further problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed process type, can throw this exception. Please correct your process type. My problem solved with the action.