# Failing to Import (some) SpecFlow Tests to TFS via PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, tfs, specflow, microsoft-test-manager

I have an automated build for SpecFlow tests running nightly in VSTFS 2015 that is populated via a PowerShell script. Most of the tests import without issue, however out of approximately 800 tests, approximately 30 are failing to import at all.

The error returned from the TFS build is:

**TF237086: The work item cannot be saved because at least one field contains a value that is not allowed.**

As this is a script, it seems odd that these particular tests, consistently fail to import.

The script is added below (mostly pulled from ye olde interweb):

```
    [CmdletBinding()]

    $storage = "$env:BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY\AcmeCo.Acceptance.Tests.dll"

    Write-Host "Importing tests from '$storage'"

    & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TCM.exe' testcase /collection:$env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI /teamproject:"AcmeCo" /import /storage:$storage /category:"SomeSuite1" /syncsuite:135777
    & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TCM.exe' testcase /collection:$env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI /teamproject:"AcmeCo" /import /storage:$storage /category:"SomeSuite2" /syncsuite:148870
    & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TCM.exe' testcase /collection:$env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI /teamproject:"AcmeCo" /import /storage:$storage /category:"SomeSuite3" /syncsuite:135775
    & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TCM.exe' testcase /collection:$env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI /teamproject:"AcmeCo" /import /storage:$storage /category:"SomeSuite4" /syncsuite:148872

    & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TCM.exe' testcase /collection:$env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI /teamproject:"AcmeCo" /import /storage:$storage /category:"SomeSuite5" /syncsuite:135781
    & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TCM.exe' testcase /collection:$env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI /teamproject:"AcmeCo" /import /storage:$storage /category:"SomeSuite6" /syncsuite:135782
    & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TCM.exe' testcase /collection:$env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI /teamproject:"AcmeCo" /import /storage:$storage /category:"SomeSuite7" /syncsuite:148869

    Write-Host "Tests imported"

    Write-Host "Updating test plans"
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client')
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client')
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client')

    # Find all test plans using this build definition
    $tpc = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)
    $tcm = $tpc.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.ITestManagementService])
    $buildServer = $tpc.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer])
    $teamProject = $buildServer.GetBuild($Env:BUILD_BUILDURI);
    $testProject = $tcm.GetTeamProject($teamProject.TeamProject);
    $testPlans = $testProject.TestPlans.Query("SELECT * FROM TestPlan")

    $matchingTestPlans = @()
    foreach($testPlan in $testPlans)
    {
        Write-Host "The current Test Plan build definition is: '$testPlan.BuildFilter.AreaPath'"

        if($testPlan.BuildFilter.AreaPath -contains 'AcmeCo Test Plan')
        {
            $matchingTestPlans += $testPlan
        }
    }

    # Update test plans with latest build
    if($matchingTestPlans)
    {
        Write-Host "Updating test plans using '$Env:BUILD_BUILDDEFINITIONNAME' to '$Env:BUILD_BUILDURI' ($($matchingTestPlans.count) matching test plans)"

        foreach ($matchingTestPlan in $matchingTestPlans) {
            $matchingTestPlan.BuildUri = $Env:BUILD_BUILDURI
            $matchingTestPlan.Save()
        }

        Write-Host "Test plans updated"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Warning "Found no test plans to update."
    }
```

Any ideas as to why some tests woulfd fail to import, or has someone come across this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach to find/narrow down the error is creating the failed automated Test case manually in MTM.

Actually to create a test case, only "**Title**" value is needed. However, you should also double confirm if there are some  wrong default value of a field in your test case. Because at least one field contains a value that is not allowed will lead to this error. Which means this maybe a test case template error.

More ways to troubleshoot it please have a look at this similar question: [How to troubleshoot TFS error TF237086 "The work item cannot be saved..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200162/how-to-troubleshoot-tfs-error-tf237086-the-work-item-cannot-be-saved)

Comment: Thanks for your input... I have tried making changes to the tests, but can't see any significant difference from the other successfully imported tests, including tests withn the same 'Feature' file. Befuddled.

Comment: So. Given that the "Title" is the only main field required and the tests are automated, I looked at the length of the tests compared to others. Turns out there is most likely a character limit for the Title field.

Comment: Either that, or there is a charater encoding issue. Addressing both of these factors ensures successful test import. Huzza!